# What makes Keycloak's AuthGuard class throw this error in an Angular 14 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

I am working on an app in Angular 14 that requires authentication/authorization, reason for witch I use **[Keycloak Angular](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular)**. I need to **guard certain routes**.

As per the instructions, I have first installed Keycloak Angular with:

```
npm install keycloak-angular keycloak-js
```

In `shared/auth-guard.service.ts` I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Router,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {

  constructor(
    protected override readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I have imported the above service in my application's routing module:

```
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component:  HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component:  LoginComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component:  ProfileComponent }
];
```

#### The problem

Importing the `AuthGuard` service throws the error:

```
Property 'isAccessAllowed' in type 'AuthGuard' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'KeycloakAuthGuard'.
```

The error refers to the `isAccessAllowed()` method in the `auth-guard.service.ts` file.

#### Questions

1. What is causing this error?
2. What is the easiest and most reliable way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method implementation does not match the type definition of the base class because you do not return anything if the user is authenticated.

The method definition from `keycloak-angular` for `isAccessAllowed()`:

```
abstract isAccessAllowed(route: ActivatedRoute, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean | UrlTree>;
```

The method has a return type of `Promise<boolean | UrlTree>`.

You need to return a value if the user is already authenticated. They can access the route and the guard should indicate that. Try making this change:

```
public async isAccessAllowed(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
) {
  if (!this.authenticated) {
    await this.keycloak.login({
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
    });
  }
  return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**
You add it to your routes like so:

```
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component:  HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component:  LoginComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component:  ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

See the [Angular docs on route guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

Comment: Great, how do I use it in the routes file?

Comment: I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: I hit the problem, that `this.authenticated` is always undefined... Any idea why? With this clicking on the guarded route, I hit an infinite redirect loop...